# OpenBSD cannot find host names

Tags: dns, openbsd, vps

I have an OpenBSD instance under vultr. I installed OpenBSD 5.8 and I can `ssh` into it just fine. But I can't seem to use `pkg_add`, `ftp`, `ping` or any other internet-dependent program.

For example, I've tried using `ping`; it works when pinging 8.8.8.8, but not when pinging something like `www.google.com` ("unknown host"). Does this mean it's some kind of firewall issue?

The same problem applies to the other programs, they can't reach the host.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to be able to use ..."?  Not found?  Core dumped?  Operation not permitted?  Host Unreachable? Network unreachable?  Could not open connection to host?  … … … … … … … … … … …  Are you trying IP addresses?  `ping 8.8.8.8` is a good test.  … … … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have `DNS servers` in `/etc/resolv.conf` and if not add at least one.

**Example**

```
#check dns servers
> cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8

#add one dns server
> echo nameserver 8.8.4.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf

#check dns servers again
> cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Note that the addresses above are just an example, they won't work on your system. Consult your VPS provider's documentation to see what their DNS servers are.

Comment: If you can ping 8.8.8.8 then you can use that as a nameserver